# Extract the content from a file between two match patterns (Extract only HTML from a file)

Tags: bash, scripts, grep, awk

I have file which contains different kind of text formats, my goal is to extract only HTML part and create a file with this HTML code. I think it is possible with `grep` or `awk`. My file contains also lines as this:

```
Sender name `<test@email.com>`
```

I wrote this script `cat file1.html | grep -E "<[^>]*>"`. But the problem is that it outputs also the lines as `Sender name`, etc. I want to extract the content only after the `<html>` tag. So this is not useful for me:

```
Return-Path: <test@test.com>
    for <test@localhost> (single-drop); Thu, 21 Sep 2017 18:34:07 +0400 (+04)
Return-path: <test@test.com>
    (envelope-from <test@test.com>)
References: <test@test.com>
From: test user <test@test.com>
X-Forwarded-Message-Id: <test@test.com>
Message-ID: <test@test.com>
In-Reply-To: <test@test.com>
```

Comment: you need to be more specific... you have just one file? can you add an example. Please update the original question with that information.

Comment: yes i want only see everything between <html>  * </html>

Comment: Thanks but not working this Sed

Comment: Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/text-between-two-tags

Comment: Does `grep -o "<[^>]*>" file1.html` is what you expect?

Comment: no but i understand how to do that

Comment: Hello, DaviD, would you post your own solution as an answer? Also I'm wondering, does my answer meet your question?

Comment: `cat test.txt|awk '/<html/{p=1; s=$0}p && /<\/html>/{print $0 FS s; s=""; p=0}p'  ` This is what i have done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can achieve this goal by the tool **`sed`** *- stream editor for filtering and transforming text*. The short answer is given under **point 5** below. But I've decided to write a detailed explanation.

**0.** First let's create a simple file to test our commands:

```html
$ printf '\nTop text\nSender <example@email.com>\n\n<html>\n\tThe inner text 1\n</html>\n\nMiddle text\n\n<HTML>\n\tThe inner text 2\n</HTML>\n\nBottom text\n' | tee example.file

Top text
Sender <example@email.com>

<html>
        The inner text 1
</html>

Middle text

<HTML>
        The inner text 2
</HTML>

Bottom text
```

**1.** We can crop everything between the tags `<html>` and `</html>`, including them, in this way:

```bsh
$ sed -n -e '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p' example.file

<html>
        The inner text 1
</html>
```

- The option `-e script` (`--expression=script`) adds a script to the commands to be executed. In this case the script that is added is `'/<html>/,/<\/html>/p'`. While we have only one script we can omit this option.
- The option `-n` (`--quiet`, `--silent`) suppress automatic printing of pattern space, and along with this option we should use some additional command(s) to tell `sed` what to print.
- This additional command is the print command `p`, added to the end of the script. If `sed` wasn't started with an `-n` option, the `p` command will duplicate the input.
- Finally by the two comma separated patterns - `/<html>/,/<\/html>/` - we can specify a range. Please note we using `\` to escape the special character `/` that plays role of delimiter here.

**2.** If we want to crop everything between the tags `<html>` and `</html>`, without printing them, we should add some additional commands:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/{ /html>/d; p }' example.file

        The inner text 1
```

- The curly braces, `{` and `}`, are used to group the commands.
- The command `d` will delete each line that maces to the expression `html>`.

**3.** But, our `example.file` has also upper case `<HTML>` tags. So we should make the pattern match case insensitive. We could do that by adding the flag `/I` to the regular expressions:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/<html>/I,/<\/html>/I{ /html>/Id; p }' example.file

        The inner text 1
        The inner text 2
```

- The `I` modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which causes the REGEXP to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

**4.** If we want to remove all HTML tags between the `<html>` tags we could add an additional command, that will parse and 'delete' the strings, which begin with `<` and end with `>`:

```bsh
sed -n '/<html>/I,/<\/html>/I{ /html>/Id; s/<[^>]*>//g; p }' example.file
```

- The command `s` will substitute the strings that mach to the expression `/<[^>]*>/` with an empty string `//` - `s/<old>/<new>/`.
- The pattern flag `g` will apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.

Probably we would want to omit the delete command in this case:

```bsh
sed -n '/<html>/I,/<\/html>/I{ s/<[^>]*>//g; p }' example.file
```

**5.** To make the changes in place of the file and create a backup copy we can use the option `-i`, or we can to create a new file based on the `sed`'s output by redirecting `>` the output to the new file:

```bsh
sed -n '/<html>/I,/<\/html>/I p' example.file -i.bak
```

```bsh
sed -n '/<html>/I,/<\/html>/I p' example.file > new.file
```

---

References:

- [**Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-31)
- [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w)
- [GNU: sed, a stream editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) | [Ubuntu: sed manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sed.1.html)
- [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file)