# Sed is dumping the entire file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed

I'm trying to parse contents of an HTML file to scrape a download directory, however I've modified it to a MWE that reproduces my issue:

```
sed -e 's|\(href\)|\1|' index.html
```

Prints the entirety of index.html. I was originally thinking that it was an issue with my expression, but this very basic expression proves that wrong.

The same happens if I remove `-e` or if I add `g` at the end.

It's been a while since I've done sed, am I doing something wrong here? Is sed getting confused with the characters in an html file?

Comment: For what you are looking for I suppose `grep` is the command to go with.

Comment: @Ravexina grep prints the entire line, I am looking for a small portion of a line.

Comment: @zx485 Changing to `/` (or `,`) does not change the behaviour

Comment: Use `grep -o` so grep prints only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `grep` to find text in a file
`sed` is better for text substitutions

If you want to list the hypertext links, you can simply grep the file like this :

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' index.html
```

Comment: This is the solution I'm using, however it may benefit from explaining what `-o` does - would make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 2):

That you've explaned sounds as the normal behaviour of `sed` used with the command `s`ubstitution. I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```bsh
sed -nr 's/^.*href="(http.*)".*$/\1/p' index.html
```

Where:

- `/` is used as delimiter in this case (you can use `|` or `#`, etc.).
- The option `-n` (`--quiet`, `--silent`) suppress automatic printing of pattern space, and along with this option we should use some additional command(s) to tell sed what to print.
- This additional command is the print command p, added to the end of the script. If sed wasn't started with an -n option, the p command will duplicate the input.
- The option `-r` enables the extended regular expressions. Without this option our command can be:

  ```bsh
  sed -n 's/^.*href="\(http.*\)".*$/\1/p' index.html
  ```
- The command `s` means substitute: `#<string-or-regexp>#<replacement>#`.
- `^` will match to the beginning of the line. `$` will match to the end of the line.
- within the the , the capture group `(http.*)`, will be treated as the variable `\1`.

Example of usage:

```bsh
$ cat index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
</body></html>

$ sed -nr 's/^.*href="(http.*)".*$/\1/p' index.html 
https://www.w3schools.com
```

More examples:

- [Extract the content from a file between two match patterns (Extract only HTML from a file)](https://askubuntu.com/q/962551/566421)
- [Awk commands find and replace string and print every thing after key word](https://askubuntu.com/q/1074853/566421)
- [Converting numbers in a CSV file to their corresponding URLs](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039143/566421)

Answer (score 1):

This may be overly cumbersome, but I think it would work for you, as long as your href contents contains no spaces.

```
grep "href" index.html |tr ' ' '\n'|grep "^href" |cut -f2 -d'='
```

The first `grep` singles out only lines that contain the href. The `tr` converts spaces to newlines. The second `grep` grabs just the href section you were interested in. Finally, the `cut` grabs everything after the "`href=`".

Comment: I am actually looking for what's after the href, so I'm looking for `href="[I want this content]"`

Comment: And that's what you get, except it's wrapped in quotes. If you use `cut -f2 -d'\"'` instead, it should give the contents of the href line. Again, much more cumbersome than what others proposed, but I was not aware of the `grep -o` oprion.